# 6 Normals of an Ellipsoid

Tags: analytic-geometry

**Prove that the six normals of an ellipsoid from an external point lie on a cubic curve.**
  Let $$x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2$$ be an ellipse .

Let $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$  be a point external to it from which six normals are drawn.

Clearly the feet of the normals are of the form $$ (a^2\alpha/a^2+k)etc$$

Let a plane $$ux+vy+wz+d=0$$ cut the ellipsoid at one of the feet of the normal, so we can prove that at least one nomral lie on a curve which is a cubic in K.
But how to show that this plane would intersect the ellipsoid at 6 places and those 6 points would be a cubic curve ?
Any other method would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Pls refer to [Geometry & Vectors](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=uwDfHbyl1IMC&pg=SL22-PA464&lpg=SL22-PA464&dq=six+concurrent+normals+ellipsoid&source=bl&ots=mEcVUdjeuI&sig=ACfU3U2OOIBTVlGvKg-kAH2Fc5WiyJs0UQ&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi43PDg85DpAhWCyYsBHR63DNAQ6AEwBXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=six%20concurrent%20normals%20ellipsoid&f=false),

Comment: [Text Book Of 3-D Conicoids](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=djlAIEBTRCAC&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=six+concurrent+normals+ellipsoid&source=bl&ots=EHbPnmV1Bh&sig=ACfU3U1s2a1U5kt0UWiT6vtskxEGGJeNeA&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi43PDg85DpAhWCyYsBHR63DNAQ6AEwBnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=six%20concurrent%20normals%20ellipsoid&f=false) and

Comment: [Analytical Solid Geometry](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=uBg7QkHu9zcC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=six+concurrent+normals+ellipsoid&source=bl&ots=pXuJHiTsk1&sig=ACfU3U2Guxhckvw0M5bUwx-4VDiNiKJhzA&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi43PDg85DpAhWCyYsBHR63DNAQ6AEwB3oECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=six%20concurrent%20normals%20ellipsoid&f=false).